# foreach works even without exporting variable and specifying package dependency

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

Reading the doc and SO questions, it seems that `foreach` requires me to specify:

> .packages     character vector of packages that the tasks depend on.
>
> .export    character vector of variables to export. This can be useful
>   when accessing a variable that isn't defined in the current
>   environment.

However, the following code works even though each of my task depends on `library(tree)` and variable `formulas`. Why don't I have to specify `.packages="tree", .export="formulas"`?

```
library(tree)
data(iris)

registerDoMC(2)
formulas <- c(as.formula("Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width"),
              as.formula("Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width"))
Res <- foreach(i=(1:2)) %dopar% {
   formula <- formulas[[i]]
   grown_tree <- tree(formula, data=iris)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doMC backend uses the mclapply function and mclapply forks its workers, so the workers inherit their environment from the current process. Therefore you don't have to use the `.packages` option to load packages that are already loaded or use the `.export` option to export variables that are defined in the current environment. Backends such as doSNOW, doMPI and doRedis don't use fork, so foreach loops that work with doMC may not work on these backends.

I think it's a good practice to use those options with doMC because it makes the code more portable, but as you've discovered, it isn't always necessary.