# Using fread with foreach and doParallel in R

Tags: r, parallel-foreach, doparallel

I used `fread` with `foreach` and `doParallel` package in R 3.2.0 in ubuntu 14.04. The following code works just fine, even though I didn't use `registerDoParallel`.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(data.table)

write.csv(iris,'test.csv',row.names=F)

cl<-makeCluster(4)

tmp<-foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% { t <- fread('test.csv') }

tmp<-rbindlist(tmp)

stopCluster(cl)
```

However, when switching to Windows 7 it no longer works, with or without 'registerDoParallel'.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
#library(doSNOW)
library(data.table)

write.csv(iris,'test.csv',row.names=F)

cl<-makeCluster(4) 
registerDoParallel(cl)
#registerDoSNOW(cl)

tmp<-foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% { t <- fread('test.csv') }

tmp<-rbindlist(tmp)

stopCluster(cl)
```

'doSNOW' package doesn't work either. Below is the error message.

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "fread""
```

Does anyone have any similar experience?

A follow up question is regarding nested `foreach`. It seems the following won't work.

```
cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl , library(data.table))

tmp<-foreach(j=1:10) %dopar% {

            tmp1<-foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% {
                          t<-fread('test.csv',data.table=T)
                   }  
            rbindlist(tmp1)
      }
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: note without the `registerDoParallel` it will not run in parallel (you only get a warning the first time). To get `fread` to work you may need to pass the functions to each cluster via, something like `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))` (untested)

Comment: might be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345271/r-how-does-a-foreach-loop-find-a-function-that-should-be-invoked and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341210/foreach-works-even-without-exporting-variable-and-specifying-package-dependency

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out. I also get this warning only for the first time. Looks like I have the same problem for both ubuntu and windows.

Comment: With `registerDoParallel(cl)` in ubuntu I got the same error message `Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "fread""`.

Comment: @user20650, thanks for the tips. `foreach(i=1:10,.export='fread')` can solve the problem.

Comment: This also seems to work on ubuntu `clusterEvalQ(cl , library(data.table))` after registering the backend

Comment: Cool. If I have more than one functions from different libraries, does it work if I use `clusterEvalQ` to add all the functions to the cluster?

Comment: `clusterEvalQ(cl , c(library(data.table), library(foreach)))` but i wouldnt imagine this is the way to go

Comment: You are right again, @user20650. It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to `user20650` for the reference in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345271/r-how-does-a-foreach-loop-find-a-function-that-should-be-invoked). Basically it can be solved by setting `.export='fread'` in the `foreach` function.

More precisely, the following will fix the problem.

```
 tmp<-foreach(i=1:10,.export = 'fread') %dopar% { 
              t <- fread('test.csv',data.table=T) 
      }
```

To my follow up question regarding nested `foreach`, `user20650` answered it in his comments. Namely,adding `clusterEvalQ(cl , c(library(data.table),library(foreach)))`. The following code seems to work both in ubuntu and windows.

```
cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl , c(library(data.table),library(foreach)))

tmp<-foreach(j=1:10) %dopar% {

     tmp1<-foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% { t <- fread('test.csv',data.table=T) }
     rbindlist(tmp1)
     }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927693/how-can-i-parallelize-a-double-for-loop-in-r?answertab=votes#tab-top about the double for loop