# How can I parallelize a double for loop in R?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I've been trying to parallelize my code because currently I'm using a double for loop to record results. I've been trying to see how to use the SNOW and doParallel packages in R to do this.

If you would like a replicable example, just use

```
residual_anomalies <- matrix(sample(c('ANOMALY','NO SIGNAL'),300,replace=T),nrow=100)
```

instead of using these three lines

```
inputfile <- paste0("simulation_",i,"_",metrics[k],"_US.csv")
data <- residuals(inputfile)

residual_anomalies <- conceptdrift(data,length=10,threshold=.05)
```

in the nested for loop. The whole code is below.

```
source("GetMetrics.R")
source("slowdrift_resampling_vectorized.R")

metrics <- unique(metrics)
num_metrics <- length(metrics)

f1_scores_table_raw = data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=46))
f1_scores_table_pred = data.frame(matrix(ncol=10,nrow=46))

rownames(f1_scores_table_raw) <- metrics
colnames(f1_scores_table_raw) <- paste0("Sim",1:10)

rownames(f1_scores_table_pred) <- metrics
colnames(f1_scores_table_pred) <- paste0("Sim",1:10)


for(k in 1:num_metrics){

  for(i in 1:10){
    #inputfile <- paste0("simulation_",i,"_",metrics[k],"_US.csv")
    #data <- residuals(inputfile)

    #residual_anomalies <- conceptdrift(data,length=10,threshold=.05)

    #the above is how I get the data frame but I'll create another one for reproducibility.
    residual_anomalies <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c('ANOMALY','NO SIGNAL'),300,replace=T),nrow=100))
    names(residual_anomalies) <- c("Raw_Anomaly","Prediction_Anomaly","True_Anomaly")

    #calculate precision and recall for an F1 score

    #first for raw data

    counts <- ifelse(rowSums(residual_anomalies[c("Raw_Anomaly","True_Anomaly")]=='ANOMALY')==2,1,0)
    correct_detections <- sum(counts)

    total_predicted = sum(residual_anomalies$Raw_Anomaly =='ANOMALY')
    total_actual = sum(residual_anomalies$True_Anomaly =='ANOMALY')

    raw_precision = correct_detections / total_predicted
    raw_recall = correct_detections / total_actual

    f1_raw = 2*raw_precision*raw_recall / (raw_precision+raw_recall)

    #then for prediction (DLM,ESP,MLR) data

    counts <- ifelse(rowSums(residual_anomalies[c("Prediction_Anomaly","True_Anomaly")]=='ANOMALY')==2,1,0)
    correct_detections <- sum(counts)

    total_predicted = sum(residual_anomalies$Prediction_Anomaly =='ANOMALY')
    total_actual = sum(residual_anomalies$True_Anomaly =='ANOMALY')

    pred_precision = correct_detections / total_predicted
    pred_recall = correct_detections / total_actual

    f1_pred = 2*pred_precision*pred_recall / (pred_precision+pred_recall)

    f1_scores_table_raw[[k,i]] <- f1_raw
    f1_scores_table_pred[[k,i]] <- f1_pred
  }

}
```

Before, I was using foreach on the outer loop with a %dopar% but the issue I'm having is that I kept getting the issue '%dopar%' not found. Should I parallelize both loops or just one?

Also I know foreach creates a list and stores it into a variable, but can I still have other variables store data in my foreach loop? For example, I still want to record data into my f1_scores_table_raw and f1_scores_table_pred arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: I can only kind of tell what you want (the confusion could be on my end and not be your question), but much of the functionality you're looking for is in the `ROCR` package (precision-recall curves and the like). I'd consider starting there. Also, maybe add what you think the bottleneck is that demands parallel processing (i.e. is the metrics vector really big? Do you have a lot more files than the hard-coded 10 in the nested `for` loop?). This could be something solve-able with a bit of vectorization instead of parallelization.

Comment: I have 46 metrics and 10 simulations for each metric. How would I vectorize this though?

Comment: Since the same metrics are calculated on all simulations, isn't it amenable to `lapply` (or if you're feeling like the parallel route is ideal, `clusterApplyLB`)? I think the better question is "where is the bottleneck?". It seems like overkill to nest parallel statements for such seemingly non-computationally-intensive calculations as above. Or I could have no idea. Also, your question wasn't about the appropriateness of the approach, but just help with the approach, so sorry to criticize without really helping.

Comment: It is computationally intensive inside the for loop. The conceptdrift function in particular takes an extremely long time even with vectorization.

Comment: I see what you mean about lapply though. I'm going to try these instead of nested for loops.

Answer (score 5):

Foreach will automatically handle this if you use the `%:%` operator between loop levels (see the "nesting" vignette):

```
require(foreach)
# Register parallel backend

foreach (k = 1:num_metrics) %:% # nesting operator
  foreach (i = 1:10) %dopar% {
    # code to parallelise
}
```

Comment: Where do I place mention of packages that are used by the code within the nested loop? With the outer or inner for each?